# Theme.json_ Set default columns for gallery

Tags: gallery, theme.json

I want to set a default number of columns for the gallery block within the theme.json-file. Is that possible? I couldn't find anything regarding this.

I tried some things under settings

```
"blocks": {
   "core/gallery": {
         "layout": {
              ....
      }       
   }
}
```

but I'm not sure if that is the right place and what you'd have to put there.

Thanks for your help!